# Is it possible to cancel nsoperation without access to it?

Tags: ios, nsoperation

I need to use a library which is not woking properly. After calling some method it creates some `NSOperation`, which never finishes and ends up with sleeping state `mach_msg_trap` error and as because I don't have the instance of these operations, I'm unable to cancel it.
Is it possible to cancel it without access?

Comment: No. To stop/cancel a `NSOperation` you should have access to it.

Comment: Technically, you would also be able to cancel the operation if you had access to the hosting `NSOperationQueue`, which I'm pretty sure you don't have access to either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that even if you had access to the `NSOperation` or its queue, "cancel" doesn't mean "make go away." It just means "don't start if it hasn't been started yet, and if it has been started, set the cancel flag." If the `NSOperation` doesn't check its cancel flag, then it still won't terminate. There's no way to do what you're trying to do, and this is intentional. Forcibly terminating an operation would leave the program in an undefined state.

It sounds like you either have a bug in the library, or a bug in how you're using the library (I would suspect the latter before the former, but it depends on the library). You're going to need to track down that bug and resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the `NSOperationQueue` where these Operations have been added?
If yes, you can access like this:

```
var queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
    // or
    queue = NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!

    let operations = queue.operations
    for operation in operations{
        if operation.name == "name of operation if you know it" {

            operation.cancel()
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you were going to do this, you could just use `cancelAllOperations()`. It's very unlikely that the operation in question is on either the main or current queue (if it were on the current queue, then this code wouldn't run, since the current queue would be blocked, and if it were on the main queue, the whole UI would be locked up and the OS would kill us).

Comment: Agree with you Rob, but why this code wouldn't run in the case of current queue. i think operations work concurrently